# Unable to import css file with es6 syntax using Grunt browserify with transform options

Tags: reactjs, gruntjs, browserify, babeljs

I have problem with browserify Grunt task and transform options. I am using React and in one of the component I need to import css file.

```
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';
```

During Grunt run it crushes on Error.

```
>> /Style/node_modules/react-select/dist/react-select.css:8
>> .Select {
>> ^
>> ParseError: Unexpected token
```

Configuration of browserify task is

```
options: {
  debug: true,
  transform: [
    ['babelify', {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}]
  ],
  external: [
    'react',
    'react-dom'
  ],
  browserifyOptions : {
    debug : true
  }
},
```

What am I missing? Thanks for help.

Comment: @Shota OP is using browserify, not webpack

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the [`browserify-css` transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-css) to be aple to import CSS files.

Comment: I include it like this  
`
        options: {
          transform: [
            'browserify-css', ['babelify', {presets: ['es2015', 'react']}]
          ]
        }
`
or like this
`
        browserifyOptions : {  
            transform: ['browserify-css']
        }
`
I event put in in packages.json like this
`
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-css"
    ]
  }
 `
 but nothing works...